# Prism get notified when a published event has been handled

Tags: c#, prism

I'm publishing an event (I'm using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Events).
This event will be handled somewhere else. I then want to wait until that gets handled (I don't care where or who by) before continuing on with code, I want the handler to put some status in my event arg so I can then use that status (e.g. successful print or non successfully print) before deciding what to do next.

Should I just kick off a thread and check for arg.Status (which I can get the subscribers to set when handling)?

Or Alternatively should the subscriber raise another event saying publish complete or something?

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    var arg = new PrintCustomerAccountSummaryReportRequestedEventArgument  { Customer = _viewModel.Customer, StartDate = _viewModel.ReportStartDate, EndDate = _viewModel.ReportEndDate };
    EventManager.Instance.GetEvent<PrintCustomerAccountSummaryReportRequestedEvent>().Publish(arg);
    // Wait until something has handled the event
    // then continue on and execute code.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternatives that you mentioned would be both correct. However, I would choose the second **PrintResult** event approach taking into account the simplicity for the solution and its extensibility if ***Print action*** would be intended from more than one site.

After handling the `PrintCustomerAccountSummaryReportRequestedEvent` event, the **Print Subscriber** would finally raise a **PrintResult** event where the **Print Publisher** would finish his job with the proper print summary report received by parameter:

```
public Publisher(...)
{
   ...
   PrintResultEvent printResultEvent = this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<PrintResultEvent>();
   printResultEvent.Subscribe(PrintResultEventHandler);
}

public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    var arg = new PrintCustomerAccountSummaryReportRequestedEventArgument  { Customer = _viewModel.Customer, StartDate = _viewModel.ReportStartDate, EndDate = _viewModel.ReportEndDate };
    EventManager.Instance.GetEvent<PrintCustomerAccountSummaryReportRequestedEvent>().Publish(arg);
    // Wait until something has handled the event
    // then continue on and execute code. Result will be handled in following EventHandler.
}

private void PrintResultEventHandler(PrintCustomerAccountSummaryReportRequestedEventArgument result)
{
   // Get print result and finish job accordingly.
}
```

I hope this helped you,

Regards.